# How can I vectorize this PyTorch snippet which uses two-dimensional indirect indexing?

Tags: pytorch

I have piece of code which is implemented using loops, which I was not able to implement in a vectorized manner.

```
for b in range(B):
    for i in range(M - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, M):
            interaction = (vectors[b, fields[b, i], fields[b, j], :] * vectors[b, fields[b, j], fields[b, i], :]).sum()
            pairwise[b] += interaction
```

`fields` is a BxM array, `vectors` is a BxMxMxD array. The result, `pairwise`, should be an array of size B. I thought gather / scatter would help, but they support indexing only on one dimension. Is there an efficient way to implement it?

Even without full vectorization, only vectorizing along the B dimension would already be great.

**Update**

Here is an initial attempt to do it in a vectorized manner, but it's still extremely slow:

```
comb_indices = torch.tril_indices(M, M, -1)
components = torch.arange(D, device=vectors.device).view(1, 1, -1)
batches = torch.arange(B, device=vectors.device).view(-1, 1, 1)


this_indices = fields[:, comb_indices[0, :]]
that_indices = fields[:, comb_indices[1, :]]
linearized_this_fields = (this_indices + M * that_indices).view(B, -1, 1)
linearized_that_fields = (that_indices + M * this_indices).view(B, -1, 1)

linearized_fields = vectors \
    .permute([0, 3, 1, 2]) \
    .reshape(batch_size, self.field_dim, M * M) \
    .permute([0, 2, 1])

this = linearized_fields[batches, linearized_this_fields, components]
that = linearized_fields[batches, linearized_that_fields, components]
pairwise = (this * that).sum(dim=[-1, -2])
```

Comment: What are the values of `M`, `B`, `D`? or the values of `fields` and `vectors`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'values'? These are tensors. M, B, D are dimensions - they can be arbitrary. fields / vectors are tensors, and their values are also arbitrary. Assume these are parameters to a function.

If it helps, 'fields' is a tensor of integers, whereas 'vectors' is a tensor of floats.

Comment: He is asking how big is `M`, `B`, and `D`

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu I see. D is quite small, usually less than 10. M can be a few dozen, less than 100. B is the mini-batch dimension, can be any reasonable mini-batch size, from 1 to 1000.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to build up a solution based on your optimized version:

```
i_indices, j_indices = torch.triu_indices(M, M, offset=1)
fields_i = fields[:, i_indices]  
fields_j = fields[:, j_indices]  

vectors_i = vectors[torch.arange(B)[:, None], fields_i, fields_j]  
vectors_j = vectors[torch.arange(B)[:, None], fields_j, fields_i]  

pairwise = (vectors_i * vectors_j).sum(dim=[-1, -2])
```

Please let me know if this optimizes the performance.

Comment: That's an improvement of almost 40% in both training and inference speed! If no other implementations pop up, I believe this will be awarded the bounty.

Comment: @AlexShtof , I optimized the last two lines, instead of saving the results into a variable and then use it again, you can test if this helps a little.

Comment: 40% is the *total* speed gain of your program but the improvement on this function *alone* is 100x faster (on my machine), which is very great. This means that this function is likely not the bottleneck of your computation anymore, and further speed gains on it won't speed up your program.

Comment: @LouisLac I saw an 40% improvement over my initial vectorization attempt, not over my non-vectorized code. Clearly it improves the non-vectorized code by much more, and for that I thank the author of the response :)